# Extjs validate Panel in Window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, panel

Available:
**Ext.form.Panel**:

```
this.myForm = Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel", {
            items : [{
                xtype : 'textfield',
                name : 'val1',
                fieldLabel : 'val1',
                            allowBlank: false,
                validator : function(value) { // validate val1
                    if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+[\w]*$/.test(value)))
                        return "val1 is not valid";
                    return true;
                }
            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                name : 'code',
                fieldLabel : 'val2',
                allowBlank: false,
                validator : function(value) { // validate val2
                    if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+[\w]*$/.test(value)))
                        return "val2 is not valid";
                    return true;
                }
            }]
        });
```

then transmits it to the Window:

**Ext.window.Window**:

> ```
> this.someWindow = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
>           items : [me.myForm, me.anotherPanel],
>           title : 'test',
>           closeAction : 'hide',
>           buttons : [{
>               text : 'Save',
>               handler : function() { // some actions
>                                 }
> ```

How can I validate val1 and val2 in **myForm** from **someWindow** on action: save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will call the validator functions

```js
handler: function(button) {
     var valid = button.up('window').down('form').getForm().isValid();
     if(valid) {
         ...
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or you move the save button into the form `buttons` config and add the option `formBind: true` to the button. this will disable the button as long as the form is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Those `validator` functions will validate the values as the user types, so those are sufficient for client-side validation. However, you will also want to have server-side validation of these values, since javascript can easily be modified client-side by a user who knows what they're doing.